# Docker documentation page - can the case be corrected?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

On the [documentation page for Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/docker/topics), the Docker title is entirely lowercase - "docker". Is it possible to correct this to "Docker"?

[image]

Comment: I see that this has been fixed now, thank you